# Update WebPart MenuItem/Verb from Client Side

Tags: development, web-part, javascript, ajax, editing-menu

Here is the scenario - I have a custom webpart where I added one custom menuitem with client side handler, now my requirement is when I click on the menuitem some text should be shown, for example consider the menu item is - "Guns N Rose" and when I click on it an alert box is popped with the text "Sweet Child of Mine" but on this menu item click the menuitem text should be changed to "Led Zeppelin", so when I open the menu I can see my custom menu item text "Led Zeppelin" and also change in client side handler should be made such that clicking on "Led Zeppelin" will pop up "Stairway To Heaven", this click will in turn change the menuitem text to "Guns N Rose" with corresponding event handler i.e. a toggle will occur every time it's clicked

this is easy to achieve if i use server side event handler instead of client side, but for some reason I cant afford to do that, basically i want to find a way without going through the CreateWebPartMenu event which requires a page refresh, is it possible to achieve this using web service/ajax or some other mean?

Comment: Why can't you use JavaScript ?

Comment: I can use JavaScript, if you know the JavaScript way, please post

Comment: You are adding a Custom Context-Menu right, can you post the definition file for your context menu?

Comment: actually it's WebPartMenu (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.webpartmenu.aspx), dont think you can say it context menu